# Bind asp repeater with static method

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I have a repeater on my  asp page and I want to bind that repeater with the code behind(C#).On c# page I have a static method to bind the repeater.But I am getting error

> "Object not set to the instance of an object"

the static method that I have is..

```
 [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    public static void LoadData()
    {
        Default oDefault = new Default();
        Page p = new Page();
        if ((List<AllPostInformation>)p.Session["AllNewsPostCollection"] != (List<AllPostInformation>)p.Session["CheckExistData"])
        {
            if ((List<AllPostInformation>)p.Session["AllNewsPostCollection"] != null)
            {
                List<AllPostInformation> o = new List<AllPostInformation>();
                o = (List<AllPostInformation>)p.Session["AllNewsPostCollection"];
                oDefault.rptNews.DataSource = o;
                oDefault.rptNews.DataBind();
            }
            p.Session["CheckExistData"] = p.Session["AllNewsPostCollection"];
        }
    }
  Please Help???
```

Comment: p.Session["AllNewsPostCollection"]; is not returning any thing...

Comment: I have initiate this session earlier in our code and when I debug I found that Session["AllNewsPostCollection"] have the data that is required.

Answer (score 0):

You can't instantiate the *Page* or *HttpSession* object. You should have to use `HttpContext.Current.Session` property to get the reference of Session object.

Comment: I tried this but this is not working.Still getting same error on  oDefault.rptNews.DataBind();